# Maximum area of triangle

Tags: calculus, optimization

How would you find the largest possible area of a triangle in the first quadrant bounded by the two axis and any tangent of the curve $e^{-5 x}$?

I suppose the solution involves formulating a function for the area and using the derivative to find the maximum value. But I struggle to determine the function..

Comment: Please enclose your formulas with dollar signs to display it.

Comment: Hint, For each $x$ find the tangent to the curve above $(x,0)$ and the area of the resulting triangle.

Answer (score 1):

For a given function $f(x)$ and a point $(x_0, y_0): y_0 = f(x_0)$, the tangent line is defined as

$$
y = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0).
$$

Given that $f(x) = e^{-5x}$, the derivative $f'(x) = -5e^{-5x}$, and we have a tangent line

$$
y = e^{-5x_0}-5e^{-5x_0}(x-x_0).
$$

This line intersects

- $y$-axis at $\left(x=0, y = e^{-5x_0}+5e^{-5x_0}x_0\right)$;
- $x$-axis at $\left(x=\frac{1}{5}+x_0, y = 0\right)$.

Then, the triangle of interest is a right triangle with two legs:

- $a = e^{-5x_0}+5e^{-5x_0}x_0 = e^{-5x_0}\left(1+5x_0\right)$,
- $b = \frac{1}{5}+x_0$.

$x_0 > 0$ since the triangle belongs to the first quadrant.

The area of the triangle equals to

$$
S(x_0) = \frac{e^{-5x_0}}{2}\left(1+5x_0\right)\left(\frac{1}{5}+x_0\right) = \frac{e^{-5x_0}}{2}\left(\frac{1}{5}+2x_0+5x_0^2\right)
$$

And the problem now is to find a maximum of $S(x_0)$, $x_0 > 0$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
S'(x_0)&=\frac{-5e^{-5x_0}}{2}\left(\frac{1}{5}+2x_0+5x_0^2\right)+
\frac{e^{-5x_0}}{2}\left(2+10x_0\right) = \\
&= \frac{e^{-5x_0}}{2}\left(1-25x_0^2\right) \\\\
S'(x_0) &= 0 \Leftrightarrow 1-25x_0^2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow x_0 = \pm \frac{1}{5},
\end{aligned}
$$

and $x_0 = \frac{1}{5}$ is a point where $S(x_0)$ is maximal.

So, the maximum area equals to

$$
\begin{aligned}
S\left(\frac{1}{5}\right) = \frac{e^{-1}}{2}\left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2}{5}+5\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^2\right) = \frac{e^{-1}}{2}\frac{4}{5} = \frac{2}{5}e^{-1}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: You, sir, are an absolute star!! Thank you so much.